# IS NULL or NOT IN to consider null values in the count

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When the run the below query with `t.status is NULL` it gives me different count (which i think is incorrect).

How do I get the count by `NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Duplicate')` but include `NULL` value rows in the count

For the below query i get a count of **423**

```
    select count(*) from QC10.DEFECTS d 
inner join QC10.DEFECTS_TRAN t on D.RECORD_ID=T.DEFECT_ID_FK_DT 
where 
 T.LATEST_RECORD='Y'
 and
 (t.status NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Duplicate'))
```

But when I run the below query i get **8530** as the count

```
select count(*) from QC10.DEFECTS d 
inner join QC10.DEFECTS_TRAN t on D.RECORD_ID=T.DEFECT_ID_FK_DT 
where 
 T.LATEST_RECORD='Y'
 and
 (t.status NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Duplicate'))
 or (t.status IS NULL)
```

Comment: So, which one is correct and if you've already got the answer, what is the question?

Comment: Sorry if my query is not clear. First query is not considering null values so it is not correct. Second query is giving huge count than what i have in the table with Latest_Record='Y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix your parentheses:

```
and
 (t.status NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Duplicate')
 or t.status IS NULL)
```

The query you typed returns all rows where `status IS NULL`, whether their `latest_record='Y'` or not.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is absolutely correct - NULL's are considered having no value and will not match any `IN` or `NOT IN` list that you supply.  If you want to avoid using OR, you can substitute a known unused value using COALESCE:

```
and
(COALESCE(t.status, 'NULL') NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Duplicate'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to accept X.L.Ant answer since he posted it first- Using coalesce works great too.